# How to reset PanelMenu.Button icon in runtime?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I am developing a GNOME Shell Extension, using gjs. Currently, I am setting panelMenu.Button icon as:

```js
class MenuButton extends PanelMenu.Button {
...
...
setIcon() {
    const icon_class = ICON_CLASS[this._settings.get_enum("icon")];
    this.icon = new St.Icon({
      style_class: icon_class,
    });

    this.add_actor(this.icon);
  }
...
}
```

and when settings signal triggers changes:

```js
this._settingsC = this._settings.connect("changed", () => this.resetIcon());
```

and the resetIcon() is:

```js
resetIcon() {
    this.remove(this.icon)
    const icon_class = ICON_CLASS[this._settings.get_enum("icon")];
    this.icon = new St.Icon({
      style_class: icon_class,
    });
    this.add_actor(this.icon);
  }
```

but it does not change/re-render the icon in runtime, if I reload the extension, the changes are only visible then.

How to change the Icon in runtime?